# Capturing line with several \n with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of Code:

```
<br>
Réaménagement des éclairages : Couloir de circulation de l'accueil – Salle de restauration de l'EHPA Résidence «
        Loubayssens »

</td>
```

I try to obtain:

```
<p>Réaménagement des éclairages : Couloir de circulation de l'accueil – Salle de restauration de l'EHPA Résidence «
        Loubayssens »
</p>
```

I would like to remove the `<br>` tag and to encapsulate the lines of text in `<p>` tags
but I'm unable to capture the entire line of text when it is on several lines.

I try:

```
<pre>
$pattern = '/<br>(\s*)([\w]([.*]|[\n])[\S|\w])(\s*)<\/td>/i';
$replacement = "\<p>$2</p></td>";
$source = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $source);
</pre>
```

I try also /is but doesn't work.

Could you give me some hints ?

Comment: [Looks like another job for ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: can you add more example and what you expected to get?

Comment: `/m` switch for multi-line?

Comment: @Prix I will do that, but I get an Html page with cUrl. And the Html Page in not well formed. I just pass through the html doc to try to get it more w3c compliant. Before using DomDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple example of using DOMDocument to remove the `br` tag within the `td` tag and encapsulate the text with `p` tag along with removing the empty spaces from start and end of it:

```
<?php
$str = <<<HTML
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<br>
    Réaménagement des éclairages : Couloir de circulation de l'accueil – Salle de restauration de l'EHPA Résidence «
            Loubayssens »

</td>
<tr>
</table>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$td = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
foreach($td->childNodes as $child)
{
    if ($child->nodeName == 'br')
        $td->removeChild($child);
}
$element = $dom->createElement('p', trim($td->nodeValue));
$td->parentNode->replaceChild($element, $td);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/40316)**

Comment: Waouu. seems to close all my headaches

Comment: @PatrickD glad you liked it, its just an example to get you started, you can load the cURL result on `$dom->loadHTML` and from there you navigate yourself to the places you need to fix, you can also use xpath if you have elements with ID or that can be easily traceable.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `<br>([\w\W\n]+)</td>` this will get all inside the tag br and td including the \n. click [this link](http://regexr.com?35q8e) for detailed example.

and [this link](http://regexr.com?35q8h) with replacement to `<p>`.

Comment: Thx All, it works with links provided by @Angga (thx). But in real example it fails. I get <p>sentence   </td> but missing </p>

Comment: `</p>` or `</td>` is just string you can replace with anything, the the only problem is just how to place your sentence into regex group, in my example $1. And if this answered your problem please mark it's as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex pattern:

```
$pattern = '/<br>([^<]*)<\/td>/i';
$replacement = "<p>$1</p></td>";
$source = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $source);
```

simple and dirty solution, better than wasting your time using parsers for a simple task...